# filter google api to search geocode of a particular city

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps-api-3

it is possible to filter autocomplete places (api v3) to search the streets with only a specific zip code or city?

Now my configuration is the following

```
    var options = {
      componentRestrictions: {country: "it"},
      types: ['geocode']
    };

    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input,options);
```

Now it is filtered only by country "it", I would to search all streets of that are it, battipaglia (CITY) OR 84091 (ZIP CODE)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use bounds, but you will have to be able to specify the lat and long

> bounds is a google.maps.LatLngBounds object specifying the area in
>   which to search for Places. The results are biased towards, but not
>   restricted to, Places contained within these bounds.

Comment: thanks for reply!
is possible to add some string to
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
before processing?

Comment: sure, + sting or var the usual js way